# QGIS CRS for Aruba

Tags: qgis, epsg

I am trying to open geodata from Aruba in the projection "Transverse Mercator Aruba". Does anyone know what EPSG this is? How can I view this in QGIS in the following projection:

```
PROJCS["Transverse_Mercator_Aruba", 
    GEOGCS["GCS_Aruba", 
        DATUM["<custom>", 
            SPHEROID["International_1924", 6378388.0, 297.0]], 
        PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], 
        UNIT["Degree", 0.0174532925199433]], 
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"], 
    PARAMETER["False_Easting", 10000.0], 
    PARAMETER["False_Northing", 15000.0], 
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian", -69.99294056], 
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor", 1.0], 
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin", 12.5201], 
       UNIT["Meter", 1.0]]
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you load the data into QGIS?

Comment: What sort of geodata file do you have?  If this information was in a .prj file next to a shapefile or raster with a matching name,  QGIS should load the data using the information in the file as the layer's CRS.   // In a search for standard EPSG codes, https://epsg.io/?q=aruba , it looks like there are none that match this -- it looks custom.